# SPNEGO protocol: accessing https webUI trough ssh tunnel in firefox

Tags: firefox, hadoop, ssh, kerberos, spnego

I'm trying to access a webUI through Firefox in a Kerberized environment.

I have a cloudera cluster with a few hadoop services running on it and I access the webUI's trough an ssh tunnel in PUTTY.

I want to access a webUI to check the logs of job I was trying to run. the problem is that the webUI has kerberos security enabled and can't be accessed without getting authenticated.

Authentication is possible with SPNEGO but this doesn't work correctly.

The problem I'm currently facing is that firefox doesn't reply to the www-authenticate with a correct negotiate header. the negotiation header it sends is a header for authenticating to the domain of my laptop instead of the domain of the cluster i'm working on.

**My question is:** is it possible to make firefox send a negotiation header for the correct domain (i.e. the domain of the cluster i'm tunneling to instead of my own local pc domain).